# Excel VBA For Loop Optimization - Exit when j = 2

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, exit

I'm trying to optimize code that will delete rows that meet certain criteria.  I have working code, but the following code creates 7 seconds of wait time to execute:

```
Dim j As Long
For j = 2 To Rows.Count
If (Range("J" & j).Value <> "") Then
Range("A" & j & ":R" & j).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next j
```

The following code runs instantly; however, I can't get it to work once j = 2.  What code needs to be added to stop the loop before it deletes the column headers in row 1?

```
' Delete rows where column J is not blank
For j = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If (Range("J" & j).Value <> "") Then
Range("A" & j & ":R" & j).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next j
```

Comment: If you're deleting rows you need to loop backwards.

Comment: Why don't you write `For j = ... To 2 Step -1` ?

Comment: To 2 Step -1 is the answer.  That's what happens when you just steal bits of code and you don't actually know what it all means!  Apologies for the lack of indentation...my original format of code got an error from stackoverflow saying all code needed indention of 4 spaces.  I took that too literally.  Rookie mistakes.  Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: the 4 spaces are required for the Markdown syntax to recognize a code block as such - you can still preserve your original & correct indentation: just paste your code, then select it all and press Ctrl+K (or use the `{}` button in the editing toolbar)

Comment: I'd also add that the first block of code is stepping through all the rows, while the second starts at the last row containing data - that's got to be saving a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should looking backward for deletions. If you do the deletions from `row#2` to the last row, there might be some rows should be deleted but remained there. Take this for example, assuming we are going to delete `row#3` and `row#4`. If we do it forward, the `row#4` becomes to new `row#3` after deleting old `row#3`. And the next row to be checked is `row#4`, that is the original `row#5`. So the data in `row#4` is actually in `row#3` now and it'll never be deleted.

However, when your data is quite massive, the deletions would take so many resource that it drags down the speed. It would be better to find all the ranges to be deleted and delete them at once in the end. We can do it by `Union` method. And this can also prevent the problem mentioned before, so we can do it forward as other loops.

Lastly, you can avoid selecting ranges since it is not so efficient. `Range().Delete` can simply delete the range and without selecting it.

The code would be like this.

```
'pseudo code
Sub deletion()
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If shouldBeDeleted Then
             If deletingRng Is Nothing Then
                 Set deletingRng = Cells(i, X)
             Else
                 Set deletingRng = Union(deletingRng, Cells(i, X)
             End If
        End If
     Next i

     deletingRng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```